# How to find a duplicate in an array? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

How can I find duplicates in my array? I put a max of 3 `Clients`. When I have 2 `Client`s, it updates the existing `Client`s with the incoming `Client`s, but when I have 3 `Client`s, it stops updating the existing `Client`s with the incoming `Client`s. The server still receives the data and the `Client` still sends the data, but it doesn't update it.

I have looked at a few posts here about duplicates in an array but I'm unable to understand them.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the `j < 3` or the `i < 3` but I'm not really sure. How can I properly detect duplicates and remove them?

```
  //Initialize Client
  Client clients[3]; //Max of 3 clients
  initClient(clients);


  while (1){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {//Existing Client
        for(int j = i; j < 3; j++) {//Incoming Client
            if(j != i) {
                if (clients[i].port == clients[j].port){ //If incoming port has the same port as existing, then update 
                    clients[i].x = clients[j].x;
                    clients[i].y = clients[j].y;
                    clients[i].channel = clients[j].channel;
                    clients[i].data = clients[j].data;
                    clients[i].len = clients[j].len;
                    clients[i].maxlen = clients[j].maxlen;
                    clients[i].status = clients[j].status;
                    clients[i].host = clients[j].host;
                    clients[i].port = clients[j].port;
                    clients[i].address = clients[j].address;
                    clients[i].present = clients[j].present;

                    //Remove the incoming client
                    clients[j].present = false;
                    clients[j].alive = false;
                    objectCount2--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop. That `while` loop is redundant!

Comment: Use the assignment operator of `Client`.  No need to assign each member individually.

Comment: ^Write an assignment operator for `Client`

Comment: @HappyCoder Sorry this isn't the full code, this actually only happens when their is an incoming packet/data. The while shouldn't be there. So something like:


    if (indexingClient){
        //do above code (dont include the while with this)
    }

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it fine except for forgetting to check if element had been removed.

```
for( uint idx = 0; idx < clients.size() - 1; ++idx)
{
    for( uint jdx = 1 + idx; jdx < clients.size(); ++jdx )
    {
        if( clients[idx].not_removed() 
         && clients[jdx].not_removed() 
         && clients[idx].match( jdx ) )
        {
            clients[idx].assign( jdx );
            clients[jdx].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

It is similar to bubble sort. You should consider keeping your structure ordered all the time.